# How to implement pause function for Audio Units

Tags: core-audio, audiounit, audio-player

My code is based on [this example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) and a stop function is already implemented, there are functions to uninitialize and stop the audio unit:

```
    AudioOutputUnitStop(toneUnit);
    AudioUnitUninitialize(toneUnit);
    AudioComponentInstanceDispose(toneUnit);
    toneUnit = nil;
```

In the example I linked to a pause function is not necessary since there's only one frequency being played so there's no difference between pause and stop. In my implementation however, I'm playing a range of different frequencies and I want to be able to pause playback.

Any ideas how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- fade out (~10ms) the AUs' output, feed the output silence after the fade
- remember the position you stopped reading your input signal
- reset the AUs before you resume
- resume from the position you recorded above (here, a fade in of the input signal to the AUs would be also be good)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing 0 to the buffer when you playback. It is effectively a pause. 
Here's some code that you can use within the playback callback.

```
   NSLog(@"Playing silence!");

   for (int i = 0 ; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++){
    //get the buffer to be filled
    AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i];
    UInt32 *frameBuffer = buffer.mData;

    //loop through the buffer and fill the frames
       for (int j = 0; j < inNumberFrames; j++){
           frameBuffer[j] = 0;
       }
   }
```